# cant collect values from input field with getElementByTagName

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementsbytagname

I'm learning JS on in school and this task is a homework and its killing me.

I need to create an input field and two buttons. The first button needs to create given number of input elements based on the first input value, second button should take all the values from new inputs and sum it.

I simply can't get the value from new input fields, i can't move from this point for week now and everything i've read didn't helped. This is the code i made so far, remember that im a complete beginner and this task is really important for me.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var i = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        var inp = document.createElement("INPUT");
        document.body.appendChild(inp);
    }
}

function myFunction2() {
    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var ar = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT").value;
        arr[i] = parseInt(ar);
    }
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<input id="input1"></input><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">dodaj</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">saberi</button><br>
<p id="test"></p>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your myFunction2 :

```
 function myFunction2() {
      var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
      var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var ar = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[i].value;
        sum = sum + parseInt(ar);
      }
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = sum;
    }
```

You dont need the for loop again. Lets declare variable sum and add value into this.
If you don't want to add value from first input, start for loop from 1.

Comment: I used this function instead of original and the script worked, need to do some minor aesthetic fixes and will send the homework. thanks a lot

Comment: @Draza By "aesthetic fixes", do you mean "changes so that it's not so easy for the teacher to find out that I cheated"?

Comment: are you still facing any issue?

Comment: @GiteshPurbia - no issues, everything is working with your fix, thanks

Comment: @IMSoP - No, I added few <p> and styles in HTML to look nicer

Answer (score 0):

Read back this line carefully:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT").value`
```

It says "get element**s**", so there is more than one element, but then you ask for "value", so a single value; how does the browser know which of the values you want?

You already ran this function, and put the result in `arr`, and you're looping over it, with the counter `i`. So that's where you want to get your value *from*.

You then reuse that variable to put the numbers *into*; that's a bad idea, and a temptation you wouldn't have had if you'd chosen better variable names, like `listOfInputElements` and `listOfValues`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add specific class to the newly created inputs because `document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")` returns collection with your `#input1`.

Here is a code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Sabiranje</title>
    </head>
<body>
<p>Unesite izabrani broj clanova niza</p>
<input id="input1"></input><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">dodaj</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">saberi</button><br>
<p id="test"></p>
    <script>
    function myFunction(){
        var i = document.getElementById("input1").value;
        for (var j=1; j<=i; j++){
            var inp = document.createElement("INPUT");
            inp.className = 'new-inp';
            document.body.appendChild(inp);
        }
    }

    function myFunction2(){
        var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("new-inp");
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            sum += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
        }

        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = sum;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix your code but it could be wrote much better.

You had some logic issue in `myFunction2()`. Take care when you want to sum all inputs value to not include #input1. I addeded the class `generated-input` on generated inputs so they can be fetched separately.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var i = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        var inp = document.createElement("input");
        inp.className = 'generated-input';
        document.body.appendChild(inp);
    }
}

function myFunction2() {
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll(".generated-input");
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<input id="input1"></input><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">dodaj</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">saberi</button><br>
<p id="test"></p>
```